# VTABLE for abstract classes C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does an abstact classes have a VTABLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592438/does-an-abstact-classes-have-a-vtable)

Does a vtable gets created for an abstract class that have pure virtual functions and virtual functions ?

```
class Abstarct {
public:
   virtual void f() = 0;
   virtual void g() {}
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2592438/57428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just saw that none of the answers in the other topic clearly answers it.

The answer is: Yes and No.

Since the vtable and vptr is implementation-defined concept and is not mandated by the C++ Standard, so compilers are free to choose any approach as long as it does dynamic dispatching of the `virtual` functions (*pure* or otherwise).

So for the compilers which implement vtable and vptr, the answer is YES (or most likely, YES) and for other compilers which do not implement vtable & vptr and instead implement dynamic dispatching in some other way, the answer is obviously NO.

See this topic:

[How can C++ virtual functions be implemented except vtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417829/how-can-c-virtual-functions-be-implemented-except-vtable)

Comment: yes, you are right, neither topics satisfied me.